# What common dotfiles are unsafe to share?

Tags: git, github, configuration, config, dotfiles

I want to backup some select dot files that I've put work into (.vimrc, for instance) on github for ease. Are there any that are particularly unsafe to share that I should avoid?

Things I want to include:

```
.vimrc (and related)
.vim
.zshrc
.pylintrc
```

Comment: You should avoid saving .netrc and your ssh key files (the .pub is okay, but the private key isn't if it's not encrypted).  Even if it is encrypted, I'd still avoid pushing it somewhere public.

Comment: I am asking for unsafe dot files. There are certain files like .netrc and .ssh that are clearly unsafe to share - I fail to see how this is opinion based at all.

Answer (score 1):

rc files are generally used as configuration files, and are typically safe to share. vimrc files get shared quite frequently as people set up vim for various tasks.

I would not recommend including the .vim directory, as it includes system specific paths (will probably be useless when shared anyways).

Just be careful with the rc files, as it really depends what you have put in them (eg: if you put in credentials to mount a remove server = bad!). rc files are literally just a list of commands for a program to run on start up.